# Android Listen to Input Fields from other Applications

Tags: android, listener

Am working on a password manager application currently in android. I don't know how I would get my app listen to input fields and capture username and passwords so that I can store them for my users..I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Outside of security flaws, it should not be possible for you to "capture... passwords", even with accessibility APIs.

Comment: To read password fields, you'll have to implement your own keyboard(IME). Also, every time user wants to use your manager, he has to switch the keyboard manually.You can switch from your IME to other IME but not the opposite.

Comment: @PrasadPawar, could you please expand your answers?

Comment: @CommonsWare, what about username?

Comment: The accessibility API should work for that, unless perhaps the app is using `FLAG_SECURE`. However, the user is warned before enabling an accessibility service, because malware apps want to do exactly what you are trying to do: spy on user input. Many people will not enable your accessibility service, so you need to decide whether it is worth creating it.

Comment: @CommonsWare Please could you now expand your answers so that I can see a real implementation of what you're saying?

Comment: This would be a good starting point https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html

Answer (score 1):

You can read input fields using [Accessibility API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/index.html). Users will be required to manually enable your accessibility service in settings before your app can start receiving accessibility events. However, [you cannot read password fields](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent.html).

> Since an event contains the text of its source privacy can be compromised by leaking sensitive information such as passwords. To address this issue any event fired in response to manipulation of a PASSWORD field does NOT CONTAIN the text of the password.

Comment: can you please give me a guide by illustrating with a code?

Comment: I'll try and expand the answer a bit later. Please don't forget to accept/upvate right answers.

Comment: For sure, I will because am really stuck on how to move forward from here.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to 2021, This is now possible with Android Autofill Service.

Quoting the official documentation:

> An autofill service is an app that makes it easier for users to fill out forms by injecting data into the views of other apps. **Autofill services can also retrieve user data from the views in an app and store it to use it at a later time**. Autofill services are usually provided by apps that manage user data, such as **password managers**.

Here's the link to the documentation to learn about it's implementation.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-services.html